# Joomla 1.6 and 1.7 tags deletion

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

Due to the fact that Joomla 1.6 and 1.7 were both short term releases, there is no longer support for them (since February 2012) and people are advised to migrate to Joomla 2.5, may I recommend that the `joomla1.6` and `joomla1.7` tags are deleted as I personally don't see any need for them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are over 400 questions currently in those tags combined, so I disagree with deleting the tags just because of a recommendation to upgrade.  There will still be people who use those versions for whatever reasons of their own, and they can still benefit from keeping those questions around.

Comment: Completely agree. And even if there's a newer version of something and Joomla itself doesn't support it, this is a community-based site so if they can answer why not keep it.

Comment: I hear there's thing "C++" thing, let's just get rid of that C tag...

Comment: @BenBrocka: I can do without the sarcasm thanks

Answer (score 8):

Well, i strongly disagree, since (besides the fact, that of course it's a good idea to upgrade) there are still lots of websites running on these versions. Not every project can be migrated without problems to newer versions due to legacy code.

Comment: Fair enough but if this is the case then Joomla would have kept supporting it.

Comment: @Lodder then take Bill's answer as another argument to not delete them. ;)